# Count the column records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, t-sql

For example I have a table "CATcuestonario"

[image]

- It will only have one record.
- I only want to count the columns that the value 'Si' has registered
- In this case it would be 3 (columns preg1, columns preg3, columns preg4)

How do I build this query?

Comment: please show what you have tried to solve the problem by editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to unpivot with `cross apply`, then count:

```
select count(*) no_matches
from mytable t
cross apply (values(preg1), (preg2), (preg3), (preg4)) x(preg)
where x.preg = 'Si'
```

Note that this also works if your table has more than one row.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7c030fd183bd23969e0a55e957fb216)**:

```
| no_matches |
| ---------: |
|          3 |
```